# manipulate font using select

Tags: javascript, html

How can i let the user change text size and font i have a drop down and i want to let the user change the font and text size i don't want it to be just one size and and font I have tried this but it doesn't work. i want to change (font = '64px impact',) so i can edit text using drop downs i have all that code i just need to edit this part thats all

```
  var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
font = '64px impact',
w = demo.width,
h = demo.height,
curve,
offsetY,
bottom,
textHeight,
isTri = false,
dltY,
angleSteps = 180 / w,
i = w,
y,
os = document.createElement('canvas'),
octx = os.getContext('2d');

 os.width = w;
 os.height = h;

octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';
```

this is what i have in my draggable it works great is it possible to do samething like that
 for font = '64px impact'

```
 $("#fs").change(function() {
selectedDraggable.css("font-family", $(this).val());
});



 $("#size").change(function() {
selectedDraggable.css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
 });
```

Comment: So you want it to be only one select that affects font-size AND font family instead of two distinct selects ?

Comment: no sorry its hard to explain myself

Comment: let me rewrite the code

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette see if you can uderstand now

Comment: Apparently, your code is a canvas rendering script. I don't think you can change the font, via CSS after it is rendered. But you could render it again with new values. By the way, I tryed it on my side... And it renders nothing. Is what you show only a part of it?

Comment: yes look at my website http://amp.site88.net/     view the source code

Comment: Okay... Interesting! First, there is errors in the console. «selectedDraggable.css is not a function» Did you check the console ?

Comment: it works fine i can edit text by selecting one draggable at a time when their are multiple draggables

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e8hZy/312/ With dropdown font size and font family change works normal for me. Chrome

Comment: ill give it a try see if i can make it work in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT... I removed the text of my first answer since it wasn't complete.**


Now, I made the color, font-family and size selection to have effect on the rendered canvas object on click of the "Create button".
I didn't touch the other controls.... But you now have the logic of the thing.

**FIRST**, I corrected your external scripts calls that where missing the «http» sometimes... And the type declarations.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

**Then the interesting part** that I changed:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
        $(element).addClass('item' + count);

        // ----------- ADDED THIS ONE LINE BELOW ----------- 
        // ----------- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT ONE! ----------

        $(element).css({"font-family":$("#fs").val(),"font-size":$("#size").val()+"px","color": SelectedColor });

        // AND A CONSOLE LOG
        console.log("font-family: "+$("#fs").val()+", font-size: "+$("#size").val()+"px, color:"+ SelectedColor);

        count++;
        $(element).on('click', function () {
            selectedDraggable = $(this);
        })
    }
};


var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
      console.log("vm:"+font);
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());


/*  --------- I REMOVED ALL THIS BELOW... WAS CAUSING «selectedDraggable is not a function»
$("#fs").change(function() {
    selectedDraggable.css({"font-family": $(this).val()});
});

$("#size").change(function() {
    selectedDraggable.css({"font-size": $(this).val() + "px"});
});
*/

// DEFAULT COLOR
SelectedColor="#000000";
$('.foo').click(function(){
    //selectedDraggable.css({"color": $(this).attr('data-color')});
    SelectedColor=$(this).attr('data-color');           // <--  STORES THE SELECTED COLOR IN A VARIABLE
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rotateButton").click(function(){
       var x= $("#rotateInput").val();      
     selectedDraggable.css('transform','rotate(' + x + 'deg)');

    });
});


fontSize = $("#size").val();    // <-- This was my fist answer.
fontStyle = $("#fs").val();

var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    font = fontSize + "px " + fontStyle,    // <-- With this.
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,
    curve,
    offsetY,
    bottom,
    textHeight,
    isTri = false,
    dltY,
    angleSteps = 180 / w,
    i = w,
    y,
    os = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = os.getContext('2d');
console.log("onload:"+font);
os.width = w;
os.height = h;

octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';
```

Comment: take a look at my source code see if you can find something wrong http://amp.site88.net/

Comment: You have a var «selectedDraggable» AND a function «selectedDraggable»... Try to change the name of one.

Comment: The function is on line 389... And called on 425. I think the others are the var.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112741/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-fidel).

Answer (score 0):

So where is error? simple example works:

```js
jQuery('#font').on('change',function(){
jQuery('#someElementToChange').css('font-family',jQuery(this).val());
});
jQuery('#size').on('change',function(){
jQuery('#someElementToChange').css('font-size',jQuery(this).val()+'px');
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="someElementToChange">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, fugiat.
</div>
<select id="font">
  <option value="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Arial family</option>
  <option value="Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Franklin Gothic Bold', Charcoal, 'Helvetica Inserat', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Bold', 'Arial Black', 'sans serif'">Impact</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
  <option value="14">14px</option>
  <option value="32">32px</option>
  <option value="64">64px</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**
Full  working example in the comments

Comment: the error is trying to curve text  using this code http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/e8hZy/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e8hZy/313/ Here working example. Some font families may be doesn't work, because they doesn't exist in the OS.

Comment: all i had to change was the font size